# Dynamic UI generation for REST services?

Tags: rest, user-interface, dynamic

Is there a framework that can dynamically build a simple HTML form that reflects the RESTful operations exposed for a given resource? This would be very useful for us when developing rapid prototypes for demonstration purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Try with swagger, you have to configure swagger into your rest application and you can use the swagger ui, which can dynamically discover and generate ui for you to test your rest services. You can the ui as a documentation of your rest service. Hope it will help you.

Check an example swagger ui @ http://swagger.wordnik.com/

Comment: How do you use it? it's confusing

Comment: You can refer http://ufasoli.blogspot.com/2013/06/spring-mvc-and-swagger-generating_6.html